# Python requests SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO or SSL3_GET_RECORD error

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, amazon-s3, python-requests

I'm running a Python 2.7.3 application with OpenSSL 1.0.1:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jun 22 2015, 19:33:41) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ssl
>>> ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
'OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012'
```

Initially, I did this:

```
import requests
_session = requests.Session()
_session.get('https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/file.name')
```

This resulted in the following error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 497, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

After much Googling and stumbling on https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/606 and its link to http://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user.html#ssladapter, I tried this:

```
import requests
import requests_toolbelt
_session = requests.Session()
_session.mount('https://', requests_toolbelt.SSLAdapter(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1))
_session.get('https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/file.name')
```

But this resulting in a different error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 497, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
```

No matter what I do, I cannot get Python Requests to access this URL. I just don't get it. It should be simple. It should just work, but it won't.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to access the specific URL with another program (curl, wget...) from the same client system? Maybe its not the fault of the Python script but of a wrong setup of the server or some firewall in the middle.

Comment: Thanks, Steffen. When I went to capture the exact URL that was being called, I realized that some unrelated part of the program was adding `:80` to the URL so that it was `https://s3.amazonaws.com:80/...`. That definitely won't work. Stopping the `:80` from being added solved all my problems. [sigh] It has been a long day...